# how to use google-code-prettify in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am developing website which having xml, java programs. I had displayed xml and java codings in TextArea successfully.But I need to display codings without changing color what eclipse editor is displaying. So i downloaded [google code prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/downloads/list). I got clear [tutorial](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) too. It was working suceesfully.

But may i know how to use google code prettify in TextArea?

help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds to me like you are wanting to allow users to type code and have it appear with google's prettiy... I don't believe it works that way.  This plugin is usually used to *display* code. Not edit it.

Comment: i am using textarea for only displaying code. I gave readonly option to viewers, i didn't give editable option. I need to use google code prettify for textarea. That's it.

Comment: Then you are going to have to customize the plugin.  I don't think they support textareas.

Answer (score 2):

Google Code Prettify doesn't work on textareas.

Try this [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/)?

It does what you want: prettify code in textarea.